# modifying HTML through an android application

Tags: android, html, web-deployment

This may seam like a simple question, but it has been stumping me for quite a while.

Is there anyway to modify variables in an HTML code, or the HTML code itself, through an android application connected to the internet?

For example if I have a website http://count.com can I make a android application with one button which, when clicked, increments the count on the website (http://count.com).
The HTML code on the website could be a variable which is then incremented, or simple a number which is found an incremented.

I understand how to read HTML code from a website on an android application, but not how to (or if its possible to) write it.

If it is not possible if you could suggest an alternative I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

you can modify the HelloWord.html in your Android or in Desktop ( Android connects to Desktop via teamviewer). Save and FTP to the web hosting and is done.

The problem it is: if you didn't know this, you will not know how to do it even if  I told.